# iOS's Spelling Predictive Analysis - for bilingual writers?

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, spelling

I love my iPhone 6 :) But I'm fully bilingual in Spanish and in English, and about 50% of my emails are in each language. Here's the problem. While my iPhone is in English, every time I write an email in Spanish, *every single word* it automatically changes to the closest English word! Argh! And as if this wasn't bad enough, unless I click on the "quoted" option, it just keeps doing it grrrr. This makes writing in the other language very, very tedious - to the point where I can't.

I'm wondering if there's a way to configure iOS or the dictionary or an app or something so that the spelling suggestions can use the dictionaries from both languages together, or something else that achieves that effect?

Comment: Is there a Spanish keyboard that you can set the iPhone to use?  Even if it  looks the same as the English keyboard, I -think- the spell-check is tied to the keyboard rather than the phone language.  (I go between English and Japanese text, on an English iPhone; but, I don't know for sure if this is a feature of non-ascii character sets or not)

Answer (score 3):

You have to activate the corresponding keyboards on Settings > General > Keyboards > Keyboards. Then when writing on each language, tap the world icon to the left of the space bar to switch between languages. The spelling check, prediction and dictionaries will be independent. The voice recognition also switches with it.

[image: globe icon]

If you keep the globe pressed, a list will pop up, and you can chose the language directly.

[image: change language / keyboard iOS]

Esto me da una buena excusa para escribir en español (mientras no exista un "Pregunta Diferente").

[image: writing in Spanish with the Spanish Keyboard on]

As you see from the screen-grab, no spelling suggestions are made to my Spanish phrase because I had the Spanish keyboard activated while writing it. However, if I go back and tap on it with the English keyboard activated, it will get red all over.

[image: taping on the Spanish text with the English keyboard selected prompts spellchecks]

Comment: Although that is iOS 9 ;-) it should be the same in previous versions as well.

Comment: @bjbk mine? No, iOS 8.4. I run away from betas. I must be getting old...

Comment: My bad! The formatting bar threw me off. I repent!! iOS 9 has lower case letters. I should have seen that.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Swift Key, its an alternative keyboard app for iphone and it allows you to have two dictionaries active at te same time. I write words in English and in Spanish in the same text all the time without the need of changing dictionary over and over.

This is a review that I found.

One of the biggest third party keyboards on Android, SwiftKey was quick to announce its support for iOS 8 following WWDC back in June.

The main thing to say about SwiftKey is that it's clever. Yes, it has a nicely executed swipe-to-type system, but it's the way it learns that's really impressive.

SwiftKey observes how you type and adjusts its word predicting suggestion system accordingly. It'll even tap into your Google and Facebook accounts (with your permission) and see how you type there too, and if you've used SwiftKey before on Android you can tap into that existing data.

**It's also BILINGUAL, so you can type in two languages without having to switch between character sets.**

Read more at http://www.trustedreviews.com/opinions/best-ios-8-keyboards-swype-swiftkey-minuum-and-more#MM7Bwdzqkm0GjGke.99

**how-do-i-type-in-two-languages-on-iphone-ipad**

https://blog.swiftkey.com/how-do-i-type-in-two-languages-on-iphone-ipad/

Comment: nice tip. this will work.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 includes a “multilingual typing” feature.  It can handle 2 languages at once.  This list of keyboards for which it works is at

http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#quickType-keyboard-multilingual-typing